# Span grid rows and columns dynamically for an image based on the image file actual height and width ( React )

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a specific requirement which is to dynamically determine the number of rows & columns needed to be spanned based on image height. I have tried couple of ways, latest one of them is at the end of the question.

Here is the current code that needs suggestions

HTML

```
<div className="grid">
    {
     pictures.map((pic,i)=>{
      return(
        <div key={pic.name+i} className="pic-container" 
         style={{ 
             gridRowStart: pic.row, gridColumnStart:pic.col, 
             // Need to put the height & width of each image in the array 
             // in the following place to span dynamically
             gridRowEnd: HEIGHT/50 , gridColumnEnd:8*(WIDTH/1400)}}>
         <div>
            <img src={`/pictures/${pic.name}.png`} className="pic"/>
            <div className="pic-name">{pic.name}</div>
         </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(99, 50px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  max-width: 1400px;
  gap: 0px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.pic-container{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.pic-container > div{
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.pic{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Latest that I have tried:

```
const [width,setWidth] = useState(null);
const [height,setHeight] = useState(null);
.
..
...
pictures.map((pic,i)=>{
  const getDim = (e) =>{
    setWidth(e.target.offsetWidth);
    setHeight(e.target.offsetHeight);
  }
  return(
    <div key={''+pic.name+i} className="pic-container" 
     style={{gridArea:`${pic.row} / ${pic.col} / span ${Math.ceil(height/50)} / span ${Math.ceil(8*(width/1400))`}}>
      <div>
        <img onLoad={getDim} className="pic" src={`/pictures/${pic.name}.png`}/>
        <div className="pic-name">{pic.name}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
})
```

The idea behind the previous solution is that everytime we get a new image the state of width and height will get updated with the new image dimensions and then will be applied on the span. Next image will update the width and height and then have them applied on its span and so on so forth. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this maybe help you.

[Sandbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-johnson-4tbr8?file=/src/components/App.js)

Image List Component:

```
    const ImageList = (props) => {
    
    const images = props.images.map((image) => {
        return <ImageCard key={image.id} image={image} />
    });
   return <div className="image-list">{images}</div>
```

Image List Css

```
.image-list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-gap:0 10px;
    grid-auto-rows: 10px;
}

.image-list img {
    width: 250px;
 }
```

ImageCard component:

```
class ImageCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            spans : 0
        }
        this.imageRef = React.createRef();
    }    

    componentDidMount() {
         this.imageRef.current.addEventListener('load', this.setSpans);

    }

    setSpans = () => {
        const height = this.imageRef.current.clientHeight;

        const spans = Math.ceil(height / 10);

        this.setState({spans});
    }

    render() {
        const {description, urls} = this.props.image;
        return (
            <div style={{gridRowEnd: `span ${this.state.spans}`}}>
                <img ref={this.imageRef} src={urls.regular} alt={description} />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: @AnasNabulsi if you use this solution don't forget to remove the event listener from the component in the componentDidUnmount function or your gonna have issues with memory leak!

Comment: Thank you Saad, your solution gave me some insights. Separating the image container as a component and using ref with useEffect (componentDidMount) to get the height helped me better solving it, even though I had to make adjustments to the styling to fit my requirement.